# Cannot convert string to float after using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a code where I take a 3D image directory and convert all image into an single line array and save in a single csv. I have 45 image directories:

```
IMG_DIR = "\\3504"
for img in os.listdir(IMG_DIR):
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(IMG_DIR,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img_array = (img_array.flatten())
    img_array = img_array.reshape(-1, 1).T
    print(img_array)
    with open('\\3504.csv', 'ab') as f:
        np.savetxt(f, img_array, delimiter = ',')
```

I can run these individual .csv files through an unsupervised learning network. However I want to combine all 45 .csv files into 1 .csv to compare the 3D volumes against each other. I have this code to combine all of the .csv:

```
filenames = glob("C:\\Users\\rzara\\Desktop\\resized\\arrays\\*.csv")
dataframes = [pd.read_csv(f, header = None) for f in filenames]
pd.DataFrame(dataframes).to_csv("C:\\Users\\rzara\\Desktop\\resized\\arrays\\Combined.csv", header = None)
```

After I combine the files using the pandas dataframe when I try to run the code I get the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '  52.0  38.0  31.0 ... 27.0  27.0  27.0\n\n[20 rows x 2500 columns]'
```

I have tried editing the .csv manually and removing all extra characters, spaces, and returns but then get the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '...'
```

Comment: I think you might need to `concat`. Try: `pd.concat(dataframes).to_csv('...')` Without looking at your data, can't really say for sure.

Comment: My data consists of 45 .csv files. Each .csv  is a 20x2500 array of real numbers separated by commas. Each line in the .csv represents an image that was turned into a 1 line array.